# Rails: Devise - user_signed_in not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise with a Registration model/controller/views (to do new registration) and a User model to do Edit/Update/Show.

Everything seems to be working fine (registration, confirmation, etc.). I am having a problem when I try to use the user_signed method in my application. I am getting the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `user_signed_in'
```

I researched this issue on StackOverflow, and applying what I learned from several Q&A sessions, here's what I did:

In my User model (user.rb), I have the following:

```
devise :database_authenticatable
```

In my User controller, I added the following:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

But I'm still getting the error. I also tried adding the before_filter to the Registration controller and the Application controller, but I'm still getting the error message.

Any ideas?

## Work Around

I am using some_action if current_user?

as a workaround, but I am still interested in figuring out if anyone has an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a question mark

```
user_signed_in?
```

Comment: I don't get it.   <%= debug("user signed in") if user_signed_in? %> works, but
  <% if user_signed_in %>
      <%=  debug("Another user signed in") %>
      <% end %> does not work. Aren't these two sequences exactly the same?

Comment: No they aren't. Ruby convention is that a method definition that ends in ? returns a Boolean. But it's part of the actual method definition. user_signed_in by itself doesn't return anything because there is no method or variable by that name. There is one however for user_signed_in?

Comment: `?` is part of the method name. Ruby can have punctuation marks in the function names. `def a? {}`, `def a?b {}`, `def a!b {}`.